# Array of jagged arrays

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

I have several jagged arrays like this :

```
int[][] map0 = {
                    new int[]{1 ,2 ,1 ,2 ,1 ,2 ,1 ,17 ,1 ,2 ,12 ,13 ,1 ,2 ,1 ,2 ,8 ,9 ,10 ,11 ,1 ,2 ,1 ,2 ,1 ,2 ,1 ,2 ,1 ,2 },
                    new int[]{29 ,30 ,29 ,30 ,29 ,30 ,29 ,30 ,29 ,30 ,29 ,30 ,29 ,30 ,29 ,30 ,29 ,30 ,29 ,30 ,29 ,30 ,29 ,30 ,29 ,30 ,29 ,30 ,29 ,30 },
                    new int[]{31 ,32 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,78 ,98 ,99 ,79 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,98 ,99 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 },
                    new int[]{31 ,37 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,95 ,96 ,96 ,96 ,96 ,97 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,100 ,101 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 },
                    new int[]{31 ,38 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,102 ,103 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 },
                    new int[]{31 ,32 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 },
                    new int[]{31 ,32 ,66 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 },
                    new int[]{35 ,36 ,67 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 },
                    new int[]{41 ,42 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 },
                    new int[]{41 ,42 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 },
                    new int[]{41 ,42 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 },
                    new int[]{41 ,42 ,64 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 },
                    new int[]{33 ,34 ,67 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 },
                    new int[]{31 ,32 ,0 ,0 ,66 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 },
                    new int[]{31 ,37 ,0 ,0 ,104 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 },
                    new int[]{31 ,38 ,0 ,0 ,105 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,108 ,109 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,108 ,109 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 },
                    new int[]{31 ,32 ,0 ,0 ,106 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,110 ,111 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,110 ,111 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 },
                    new int[]{31 ,32 ,0 ,0 ,107 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,56 ,57 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,56 ,57 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 },
                    new int[]{26 ,26 ,26 ,26 ,26 ,26 ,26 ,26 ,26 ,26 ,26 ,26 ,26 ,26 ,26 ,26 ,26 ,26 ,26 ,26 ,26 ,26 ,26 ,26 ,26 ,26 ,26 ,26 ,26 ,26 },
                    new int[]{27 ,27 ,27 ,27 ,27 ,27 ,27 ,27 ,27 ,27 ,27 ,27 ,27 ,27 ,27 ,27 ,27 ,27 ,27 ,27 ,27 ,27 ,27 ,27 ,27 ,27 ,27 ,27 ,27 ,27 },
                    };
```

Now I want another array to hold these arrays so I can choose a random jagged array from it.
I did:

```
int[][][] mapArray = {map0,map1..};
```

But it gives me a compiler error saying `An object reference is required for the non static field, method, or property 'map0'`
`int[int[][]]` doesnt work either

Comment: Does this have to be arrays? Why not put this data into a class where it can be used more easily?  Or even a List?

Comment: This array is a representation of a map. I just want to know the index and the value to draw the map. So I just used a jagged array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot refer to other instance fields when initializing an instance field.  You'll need to initialize it in the constructor.

You are declaring the type of the object entirely correctly; there's nothing to change there.